# How can I know if an IR LED (emitter) is working, other than using a smartphone camera?

Tags: led, multimeter, infrared

I bought a lot of 5 mm, 940 nm IR LEDs like the picture below. I want to know if they are working or not. I tried the smartphone camera method, but I could not see the light. I have tested multiple of them, and I could not see the light with any of them, so I am not sure if the test itself is working or not.

I used a breadboard power supply and connected the LED like this:

```
5 V -> IR LED -> 270 ohm resistor -> ground
```

Am I supposed to see the light with the camera? Should I use a different resistor?

Is there a way to know if the IR LED is working without a camera, but with a multimeter? I have a cheap [XL830L multimeter](https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71l1G0ivRnS._AC_SS450_.jpg). With a regular LED (red, yellow), if I set the multimeter to 2 kilohm or 200 ohm, I could see the LED lighting, but the displayed value is 1 (error). If I do the same thing with the IR LED, of course the value is still 1, and I cannot see the light with the camera.

[image]

Comment: Did you confirm that your phone's camera can see the IR LED on something that you know works - e.g., your TV remote control? It might be well filtered. If so try some other cameras - USB, laptop, etc.

Comment: camera always have IR filter. You can modify some cheap USB camera by disassembling and removing IR filter.

Comment: @Transistor It turned out that 2 LED's out of 3 LED's that I tested were not working. I don't recall hearing explosions but I had accidentally connected one without a resistor, so maybe I broke the two. Also, I have found that the light is stronger when the camera is right above the LED. That is, the light is weak if I am taking the picture from the side of the LED.

Comment: The domed head of the LED determines the viewing angle. It's a lens.

Comment: Have you tried using the *front* (user-facing) camera on your smartphone? Often the front camera has less filtering than the main camera and can still pick up the IR signal. This is true on my iPhone SE 2, for example.

Comment: @user263983 the filtering is highly variable.  I use my phone as a viewer for 1064nm, but the current one is pretty weak.  My previous phone was better and I even used it for 1146nm (weak CW laser so not 2-photon excitation, but even though just below the bandgap of silicon it was close enough to pick up weakly).  Other cameras struggle even with 785nm which can be seen by eye

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not all phone cameras pick up IR LEDs, probably due to internal optical filtering. For example, my iPhone only shows a dim flicker in a dark environment from an IR remote that I know is very bright.

In general if the LED has an appropriate voltage across it (~1.2V usually) and there is appropriate current flowing, you can be pretty sure it's emitting light. If you bought it from a reliable supplier and have not damaged it, then it should be emitting light within datasheet parameters. You can verify the current by measuring the voltage across the 270\$\Omega\$ resistor (check the resistance before installing it, out of circuit)  to be 100% sure.

One way to directly test it is to connect another similar LED as a photodiode to your multimeter on a voltage range (eg. 200mV or 2V). Point one at the other and remove them from ambient light (in a cardboard box or whatever). If you turn the emitting LED on and off, you should see a change in the indicated voltage on your multimeter.

As @Seb mentions below, try both cameras. The front (selfie) camera on my phone has better IR response. Photographing things in a high temperature furnace or kiln with a digital camera can also give you the false violet image.

[image]

Comment: _"that I know is very bright"_ — bright in what sense? So bright that you can notice the flicker with the naked eyes? :)

Comment: @Ruslan I know the current and mW/sr (radiant intensity) characteristic of the LED since I upgraded both to get more range. And yes, I get the joke.

Comment: When using a smartphone camera to detect IR, it’s worth checking the front camera in addition to the rear one(s). In every recent iPhone I’ve had, the rear camera had IR filtered out, but the front camera showed IR without problems.

Comment: Also a webcam is worth a shot.  Cheap ones can be better

Answer (score 8):

In addition to the methods the other answer mentions, you can get these [IR detector cards](https://www.thorlabs.com/thorproduct.cfm?partnumber=VRC4) that glow in the visible spectrum when exposed to infrared light; I could swear they used to be more affordable than this though. I see a few available on Amazon for much cheaper, but I have my doubts as to whether they're actually real.

(If you're wondering about the physics behind it, I believe it involves the conversion of two IR photons into a single visible photon--no violation of conservation of energy here, sorry!)

They make them for UV, too, if you ever need that.

---

Note: I'm not affiliated with the company in the link above; it just happens to be the one that I know about that sells these things. They're not the easiest to find.

Comment: The other type on that page works via phosphorescence where you "charge" it with visible light which is stimulated by IR photons. These are extremely sensitive and work much better with lower power sources like LEDs. The two photon absorption type are made for high brightness sources like lasers.

Comment: Non-linear optics for just $100? Not that I have looked at the subject for 20 or so years, but I am ordering one just out of curiosity.

Comment: Thermal camera (e.g. FLIR) detect mid-IR (7000 to 14000nm). They won't see the near-IR of the LED emitter in the 800 to 1600nm range.

Comment: @user1850479 Oh, good to know! I thought the charging process would be a bit of a pain, so I chose the one that didn't require it for this recommendation; I didn't realize it was that much of a difference in sensitivity.

Comment: @GTElectronics I'll remove that section of the recommendation, then. I had thought thermal cameras were sensitive to NIR, not MIR.

Comment: I know, right? What's in those cards? Platinum?

Comment: @DKNguyen I can kind of understand it for the IR ones since they need nonlinear optics, but even the UV ones are about the same price! All you need for that is something fluorescent!

Comment: I doubt they cost very much to make. You're seeing there is the standard 1000% markup for low volume scientific parts.

Comment: @DKNguyen From some other comments, it appears they have a phosphorescent doped chemical (a salt ?) that absorbs light from the room and then remains in a metastable state, and the IR triggers the release. They're not doing the DPSS frequency doubling thing. Probably cost pennies to make.

Comment: @fraxinus up-conversion cards used crushed pieces of the same material used in frequency doubling.  The range of particle sizes means you get some phase-matching but it's dreadful.  I use those with my 1064nm ps laser, and they only work for reasonable pulse energies    They won't work here, but the phosphor sort might

Comment: @SpehroPefhany both exist, though the non-linear sort are no use here. [Further reading for anyone interested](https://www.rp-photonics.com/laser_viewing_cards.html)

Comment: @Hearth: When I used the phosphorescent cards some decades ago, the instructions made them sound like much more of a pain when they were.  If one were e.g. using a card to test hundreds of remote controllers on an assembly line, the card might become discharged, and I have no idea how long it would take to recharge, but if used for short amounts at a time and left out in ordinary light when not in use, one of those cards will become and remain charged up and ready for use.

Comment: @supercat That's good to know. Perhaps it's just reminding me a bit too much of those really bad glow-in-the-dark things you got in the 90s, that barely glowed and didn't last very long.